# How to manage UI and application logic separately in web application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have designed two HTML pages input.html and output.html (using HTML5 and groundworkscss). One is for getting information from a user in a form and another to show the output in a table.

The first page submits information to a JSP page via GET request. THe JSP page returns a XML response. How can I capture and show that information in the output.html ?

Note: I know I can include HTML code in the JSP page and show the output from there. But in this case, I do not have any control over that JSP page.

Comment: Why do you need two separate HTML files?

Comment: Hi Kramer, are you using any shorthand javascript libraries ( jquery, prototype, dojo ... ) in your front end ? If so tag the question with them.

Comment: @AlexW I do not specifically need to separate HTML files. But I don't know how to manage input and output UIs in same file

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using AngularJS to parse through XML and put the data into your html

Answer (score 1):

Key part to the solution here is **AJAX**. When we get the XML back from the JSP we want **access it from within our webpage**. This is an example of the steps to do that.

Say we have a button and a div

```
<div id="xmlresults"></div>
<button id="getxml">Click me to get jsp xml</button>
```

**Under this markup** with js/jquery we could :

```
(function() { 

 function printxml(xml) {
   /* examples for use/parse */
   xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ), $xml = $( xmlDoc );
   /* print a node value to the page */
   $("#xmlresults").html( $xml.find( "somenode" ).text() );
 }

 function getxml() {
   var reqConfig ={ url: "/xmlget.jsp", type: "GET", contentType: "text/xml" };
   var request = $.ajax(reqConfig);
   request.done(function(xml) { printxml(xml); });
   request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) { /* output error */ });
 }

    /* start the listen and call */
    $("#getxml").on("click", function() { getxml(); });

})(); /* optional anon function wrapper */
```

Hope this gets you in the right direction.